# Is it possible to imitate the turn over effect?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I use [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io).

I have the group of shapes. It looks like photo:

[image]

I can move it on the web-page. But also I need *to turn over* the photo for to see the text on the back side.

Is it possible to imitate the *turn over* effect?

I know it maybe can be done by transformation, but I can't build the transformation for this case. I need the turn over instead of usual rotate.

Comment: It can be done using a transition. An example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29942566/727316

Comment: I know it maybe can be done by transformation, but I can't build the transformation for this case. I need the turn over instead of usual rotate.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of what you mean by `turn over effect`?

Comment: For example, when you read a book you turn over its pages. I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Sure it's possible. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15904594/5385381